# Make text as hyperlink in the sms

Tags: java

everyone. 
I have a sms message with URL:
Like: "Do you want to buy https://mysuperurl.com" and i want to make my url address part as hyperlink: "Do you want to to buy **it**"? where 'it' will be link
How I can do it?

My sms send method

```
public Future<Boolean> sendSmsNotification(String to, String body) {
    try {
        logger.info("Trying send SMS");
        MessageFactory messageFactory = twilioRestClient.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", smsFromNumber));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));
        messageFactory.create(params);

        logger.info("SMS to "+to+" was send");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while sending SMS ",e);
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(false);
    }
    return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);

}
```

Where the body has String type.

Comment: I don't think you can do that; it's up to the recipient's phone to do that sort of magic.

Comment: @chrylis is correct. SMS's are plain text. Some smart phones automatically convert urls to clickable links if they are in the correct format.

Comment: @WebCode.ie thanx for answer. Can I use mms for that task?